# Crafting generic Make targets with dynamic dependencies

Tags: makefile, build, gnu-make

I have a need to generate a few object files with different load addresses. I also have a make target for invoking `objdump` to show me the respective disassembly.

```
code0:
    gcc -m32 $(CFLAGS) -Wl,$(LDFLAGS),-Ttext=$(CODE0_RELOC) $@.S -o $@.o
    objcopy -O binary $@.o --only-section=.text $@.bin

code1:
    gcc -m32 $(CFLAGS) -Wl,$(LDFLAGS),-Ttext=$(CODE1_RELOC) $@.S -o $@.o
    objcopy -O binary $@.o --only-section=.text $@.bin

dump: dump_code0 dump_code1
dump_code0: code0.bin
    objdump $< -D > $<.decomp

dump_code1: code1.bin
    objdump $< -D > $<.decomp
```

This will fail because there is no target for `code.bin`, but target `dump_code` depends on `code.bin` being present. To prevent it from being confusing (i.e. using dependency `code0` such that `code0.bin` is then produced) I thought it would be easier to create a `%.bin` target that will create the respective binary file associated with each object file (since there is also duplication of this code across all `code*` targets anyway. This target will then be a dependency for each `code*` target. However, this necessitates (or at least I *think* it does) the need for dynamically assigning dependencies. I tried something like this that did not work:

```
%.bin: $(basename $@)
    objcopy -O binary $(basename $@).o --only-section=.text $@.bin

code0: code0.bin
    gcc -m32 $(CFLAGS) -Wl,$(LDFLAGS),-Ttext=$(CODE0_RELOC) $@.S -o $@.o
```

With the logic being that a dependency such as `code0.bin` would cause this target to execute with the single effective dependency of `code0` to first build the object file.

I may be misunderstanding how the `%` character may be used to wildcard make targets. The first usesof `basename` was evaluating as empty (the second worked), so the target had no dependencies. It does make sense that the dependency tree be evaluated once at invocation, but I was hoping for a more dynamic capability.

Can this be done in Make?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is probably [Static Pattern Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern) with which you could rework your first attempt:

```
code0:
    gcc -m32 $(CFLAGS) -Wl,$(LDFLAGS),-Ttext=$(CODE0_RELOC) $@.S -o $@.o
    objcopy -O binary $@.o --only-section=.text $@.bin
```

as:

```
code0.o code1.o: code%.o: code%.S
    gcc -m32 $(CFLAGS) -Wl,$(LDFLAGS),-Ttext=$(CODE$*_RELOC) $< -o $@

code0.bin code1.bin: %.bin: %.o
    objcopy -O binary $< --only-section=.text $@
```

See the principle? `$*` in the recipe of the first rule is substituted by the matching stem of the static pattern rule (the digit in our case). This works but pattern-specific variables would probably be easier to understand and maintain:

```
# Default code reloc option
CODE_RELOC := default_code_reloc_option

# code1-specific code reloc option, if different from default
code1.o: CODE_RELOC := code1_code_reloc_option

code0.o code1.o: %.o: %.S
    gcc -m32 $(CFLAGS) -Wl,$(LDFLAGS),-Ttext=$(CODE_RELOC) $< -o $@
```

The last part of your first makefile could also use static pattern rules, plus phony targets. Something like:

```
.PHONY: dump dump_code0 dump_code1

dump: dump_code0 dump_code1

dump_code0 dump_code1: dump_%: %.bin.decomp

code0.bin.decomp code1.bin.decomp: %.bin.decomp: %.bin
    objdump $< -D > $@
```

Finally, we can use some more make tricks (discovery of source files, pattern substitutions) to automate a bit further:

```
CODES   := $(wildcard *.S)
OBJS    := $(patsubst %.S,%.o,$(CODES))
BINS    := $(patsubst %.S,%.bin,$(CODES))
DECS    := $(patsubst %.S,%.bin.decomp,$(CODES))
DUMPS   := $(patsubst %.S,dump_%,$(CODES))

# Default code reloc option
CODE_RELOC := default_code_reloc_option

# code1-specific code reloc option, if different from default
code1.o: CODE_RELOC := code1_code_reloc_option

.PHONY: dump $(DUMPS)

dump: $(DUMPS)

$(DUMPS): dump_%: %.bin.decomp

$(DECS): %.bin.decomp: %.bin
    objdump $< -D > $@

$(BINS): %.bin: %.o
    objcopy -O binary $< --only-section=.text $@

$(OBJS): %.o: %.S
    gcc -m32 $(CFLAGS) -Wl,$(LDFLAGS),-Ttext=$(CODE_RELOC) $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(BINS) $(DECS)
```

The `clean` target is a bonus gift.

All this has a significant advantage over what you were trying to do with targets that were not real files. Here, files depend on other files, except the phony targets that are just a kind of shorthand for real target files. And this is 100% in line with make's philosophy: express inter-files dependences such that make compares files timestamps and decides what is up-to-date and what must be rebuilt. Significant savings when a lot of targets are already up-to-date.

A second advantage is that expressing all inter-files dependences is parallel safe. If you run make on this makefile with:

```
make -j 8
```

(assuming you have about 8 cores on your computer), you can expect a speed-up factor of 8. Not much if you have only two source files, but quite interesting if you have hundreds of them...